# iphone/ipad : How to Enforce Apple Security Policy through iOS Application?

Tags: iphone, security, passwords, data-protection

Can anyone Help me , How to enforce apple Security Policy in my application ,

Problem/Objective : i want to enforce a pass code in start of my application , so My Application Data 
is secured , is there any method , i can do that ?

Thanks 
Much Appreciated

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: if you want your application to enforce some Data protection trough passcode Protection.. you need a security profile to do that.. You can do that with iphone explorer and Make a profile like passcode required and don't want your data to be go on icloud etc.. and then use that profile in you app to do so.. 
indead.. i done this thing.. Thanks for help :)

Comment: how about checking if the auto-lock is enabled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319044/auto-lock-iphone-ipad-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good high level intro to get you started: [Link](http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/06/How-to-build-secure-ios-apps.php) (read comments on page) and this [Link second](http://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/tag/ios-security/).

Then you have two schools:

1.Use [Apple iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreOSLayer/CoreOSLayer.html) (security section) offered services to secure product.

2.Write your own / use non-Apple security API.

Pros:

1. Robust and a lot of help out there.
2. Not so popular, less attention from hackers.

Cons:

1. Hackers are very familiar with it as it is the most widely used solution.
2. May not be as strong or robust as (1).

You can always use a mix of both. Remember it's a game (fun?) of hide and seek with the cracker/hackers. Pick your tools wisely and be creative!

Good resources on the topic:

1. [iOS Security Architecture Presentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ios%20security%20api&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=http://www.isecpartners.com/storage/docs/presentations/iOS_Secure_Development_SOURCE_Boston_2011.pdf&ei=wr38TvvuN87ViALo2YyXDQ&usg=AFQjCNHVfPIrnThXqy3VuQjzGsRNerQeow&sig2=vjzOkaAI3BKMxm_EWnbVBw)
2. [Tips on storing passwords](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad/)

Whenever you want to secure something, you need some form of non-predictable randomness generation source. Date/Time is always a good start. Then iOS devices have GPS, gyroscope data among other things (again get creative), that ensures little to no collisions in generating unique ID's to each legal customer that paid for/supported the product. For example the unique ID could restructure the modules of the product in a way that it wouldn't work unless that "key" is there to direct the execution of program through the (post-altered) modules. These modules can hold resources (images, sounds etc.) or code.

Again, just thoughts to get you started!