# Wi-fi sleeps after some time - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I created application to download files. For downloading i use `ASIHTTPRequest`. When I start download big file, and lock my device, after some time my download stops, wi-fi disables and i see Edge icon instead of Wi-fi icon. When I unlock my device, Wi-fi icon appears in 1-2 seconds. My application is not in background! How to solve my problem?

Comment: maybe 5-10 minutes in locked mode

Answer (score 4):

Two things come to mind:

Firstly enable persisten wifi connection for you app: [My iPhone app needs a persistent network connection...how to specify UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338539/my-iphone-app-needs-a-persistent-network-connection-how-to-specify-uirequiredd)

Secondly make the app request background time when it goes into the background so the actual download can continue: 
[Continuing a long running process in the background under iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430781/continuing-a-long-running-process-in-the-background-under-ios4)

Comment: Not helped( I've also set the UIRequiresPersistentWiFi to YES

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if 10 minutes after locking the device if the app would count as running in the background or not.

I'd at least try enabling background downloading in ASIHTTPRequest:

```
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

It might help and you've nothing to lose :)

Comment: I've done this already :) In background it works good BUT only when i use phone while downloading. When I lock device wi-fi turns off after 5-10 mins. On the iPad 2 wi-fi works all the time. Even when device is locked. So I think this "feature" cannot be disabled on iPhone, because it saves battery life.

Answer (score 0):

You can also prevent the IPhone to lock the screen. It'll use more battery but will solve your problem:

```
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   myApp.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Comment: IMHO huesforalice's answer is a better one, but disabling the idle timer can be useful in some circumstances. Remember to re-enable the idle timer or the user may come back to a completely dead device! See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023265/delaying-but-not-disabling-iphone-auto-lock